# After adding SQLServer dependency to Gradle, jar can't find Main class

Tags: java, sql-server, intellij-idea, gradle, gradlew

I have a Gradle project with some third party dependencies.

My jar has been working fine until I added SQLServer dependency.

Here is a snapshot of build.gradle:

```
group 'MyApp'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.60'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.6'
    compile files('mylibraries/ojdbc7.jar')
    compile files('mylibraries/postgresql-42.1.4.jar')
    compile files('mylibraries/mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre8.jar')
}

jar {
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }

    }
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'MainLauncher'
    }
}
```

Everything breaks down after `compile files('mylibraries/mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre8.jar')` has been added to dependencies. The error I get:

> Error: Could not find or load main class MainLauncher

What could be a potential problem? Thank you!

Comment: Build the jar - extract it (`jar -xvf <some.jar>`) and verify the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file - if everything is ok with it. It's a chance that manual fat jar creation messes something up. Also there's a shadow plugin for gradle - which is well tested and will build fat jar correctly. Why is `MainLauncher` without package name?

Comment: Thanks for you reply, Opal. Funny thing, just one particular library crashes the entire execution. Apart from it everything works fine. I already solved a problem by using another open-source solution. There is no package name because the MainLauncher file is located in root of 'java' folder.

Answer (score 2):

Today i faced exactly same issue and i reached to this page to get the resolution

I was running jar with below dependency

```
group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '6.2.2.jre8'
```

and i was facing exactly same issue,

> Error: Could not find or load main class

later i changed dependency with older version and it run fine after this change

> group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version:
>   '6.2.1.jre7'

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem some time ago. I just imported the project and wanted to do a gradle clean build. I had exactly the same error.

I could solve this by just making sure I had at least one migration. It may sound silly but just try to create 1 migration for your database.

At least it solved my problem and I surely hope it solves yours too!